# Как скрыть блок div после выполнения формы?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код формы

```html
<div id="form">
  <form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="iframe name">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="funds01">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="admin">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
    <button type="submit">Go to payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия кнопки отправки формы, блок id form скрылся, а блок id result появился?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно вот так.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
function getResult() {
  form.classList.add("hidden");
  result.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="iframe name">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="funds01">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="admin">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
    <button type="submit" onclick="getResult()">Go to payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result" class="hidden">
  <iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
</div>
```

С помощью AJAX:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function getResult() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200 || 302) {
      form.classList.add("hidden");
      result.classList.remove("hidden");
    };
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="iframe name">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="funds01">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="admin">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
    <button type="submit" onclick="getResult()">Go to payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result" class="hidden">
  <iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#result').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#form').style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
#result {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="iframe name">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
    <button type="submit">Go to payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

так как там айфрей,то sucess работать не будет, прийдётся проверку по другому делать,в данном случае проверка происходит в случае любого завершения запроса. Расчёт на то,что валидация стоит на форме всётаки.

```js
$('#paypal').submit(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
  data: 'параметры',
  complete: function(){
    $('#paypal').hide()
    $('#result').hide()
  }
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="iframe name">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="funds01">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="admin">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@yandex.ru">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
    <button type="submit">Go to payment</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="result">
  <iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
</div>
```